# Right-click option in Blueprism

Tags: automation, blueprism

I am using `blueprism` and I want to automate an application.

For that I need to spy one field and do right click.

But I couldn't do that give me an idea.

Answer (score 2):

sorry for the 'me too' post, just thought the previous answer was due to the misinterpretation of the question.

Anyways, I have solved this!

You need to use Surface Automation (Region Spying Mode) to achieve this.

1. Execute the spy element action and press alt thrice to enter the Surface Automation Spying
2. Select the region you wish to control (give some allowance but not too much)
3. Use a global mouse event on your main application model and enter "RIGHT" into the mouse field

Answer (score 1):

Steps to spy element/field:

1. Open Application modeler
2. Configure application path and Click on Launch Application
3. After successful launch Click on Identify Element button in Application modeler
4. Goto your launched application window and hover your mouse over the element you want to spy(a red color border will appear over the currently focused element/field)
   Note: (Default spy mode is Win32, you can switch mode using 'ALT' key)
5. Press 'CTRL+Mouse Left Click'
6. If spy operation was successful then application modeler will show currently spied element with attribute list (Verify spied element with 'Highlight Element' button)

Answer (score 0):

The right click option for Application Modeler Elements in BluePrism is only available for Global Mouse Click Events which is available via surface automation. In sending a Global Mouse Click/Mouse Click, set the mouse text to "RIGHT" as against the default empty string which is left click.

Answer (score 0):

The global mouse click/ global mouse click centre events are available based on what is the element that you have spied and on which mode you have spied. For example if you have spied a popup window button using active accessability mode and if you want to do a mouse click on it then use a navigate stage and select the spied element to see all the options. Select the global mouse click/ global mouse click center and enter left/ right in the parameter. The former event ask for x and y coordinate also. It is relative to the element you have spied. 0, 0 means it will click on top left corner of the spied element.